# Kendo grid is not paging intitially until column is sorted

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

Again the paging doesn't work until I click on a column header to sort, then the paging seems to work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#reportContainer').load('Reports/Scaffold.html', function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: Reports.ServiceURL.MyService,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: { myParam: "1" },
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },

                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    return kendo.stringify(data);
                }
            },

            batch: true,
            pageSize: 50,
            schema: {
                data: "d"
            }
        });

        $("#allGrids").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            filterable: false,
            height: 400,
            columns: myModel
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you reproduce in either JSFiddle or JSBin so we can help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you want to select `serverPaging` *BUT* you placed it in the wrong place. It is a field of `DataSource` and not of `transport.read`. You should have defined it as:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport    : {
        read        : {
            type       : "POST",
            url        : Reports.ServiceURL.MyService,
            dataType   : "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data       : { myParam: "1" }
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            return kendo.stringify(data);
        }
    },
    serverPaging : true,
    serverSorting: true,
    batch        : true,
    pageSize     : 50,
    schema       : {
        data: "d"
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget that when you define `schema.data`, you need to define also the total number of records, if it comes from the server you might have something like:

```
schema       : {
    data: "d",
    total: "total"
}
```

and the server should return some JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "d": [
        ...
    ],
    "total": 100
}
```

Where `100` is the total number or records in the server and not the number of records in `d`.

And if is **not** `serverPaging` you might simply do:

```
schema   : {
    data: "d",
    total: function(data) { return data.d.length; }
}
```

@BurkeHolland, If you want to know what was happening is that the grid was actually not doing `serverPaging` and likely not receiving `total` or not being able of computing it. It was neither in `serverPaging` mode nor in `serverSorting` mode, so when @SkildLobster clicked on the title, it sorted the results (maybe they were already sorted) and then it computed the total number of records from the grid data length being finally able of computing the page.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I hate it when I miss something small like that. Also, I used the last total example:

Comment: I've done and seen so many _little_ mistakes with KendoUI `DataSource` that I'm planning to develop a guided-UI for defining / configuring it. You are not alone!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an MVC Kendo grid, I couldn't see an obvious way to add a schema. I solved the problem by getting the grid to sort after loading as follows. In the grid, I added a databound event:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<tpnconnect.com.Models.Tools.NonWorkingDay>()
            .Name("Holiday_Grid")
            .Events(e => e
                .DataBound("sortHolidayGridByDate")
            )
```

I used a JavaScript variable to prevent the event from being triggered more than once:

```
<script>
    var firstBind = true;

    function sortHolidayGridByDate() {
        if (firstBind == true) {
            firstBind = false;
            var grid = $("#Holiday_Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dsSort = [];
            dsSort.push({ field: "NonWorkingDate", dir: "desc" });
            grid.dataSource.sort(dsSort);
        }
    }
</script>
```